# Use interrupt to determine a change in IR detector

Tags: operational-amplifier, interrupts, comparator, differential

I have build a schematic to read a counter. The counter has a white point at one of the digits, that I detect with a IR transmitter-receiver. The voltage at the receiver changes from 2.2 to 2.5 volts (with some noise between) when te white point passes. So I use a opamp diff amplifier to change the voltage range to 1 - 3 volts. That signal goes to opamp comparator that changes at 2.2 volt input. I measured the voltage and indeed, only when the white point passes, the voltage is more than 2.2 volts
The output from the last one goes to a arduino that I programmed to count the signal via a interrupt.
The problem is now that I have false counts, but I cannot find why. I use a software debounce that is sure big enough to avoid false detections caused by bounces.
I think it has something to do with the hardware. Hereby a schematic.
Unfortunatly I have no scoop...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkUceS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My preference would be to go for a software-only solution: let the Arduino A/D  the fotodiode input at a regular bas (1kHz?). You can log what you sample, and analyse at your leisure when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to apply hysteresis to OA2 - this has the effect of minimizing the effect of noise as the signal from OA1 gets close to the threshold point defined by R7. Try a 1k ohm in series with the signal from OA1 to non-inverting input of OA2 and something like a 100k to 1M ohm from output of OA2 back to its non-inverting input. The size of this feedback resistor will set the amount of hysteresis.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy's recommendation for hysteresis, and I want to also suggest that you use a better op amp than the LM358. With a supply voltage of 5V you can't guarantee that the output voltage of an LM358 will get any higher than about 3.5V, which is a pretty sloppy logic 1 level. You should look for an op amp that has a "rail-to-rail" output instead.

Comment: Thanks! Can you advice better opamps for that issue?

Comment: Try an AD8605 - it's fast enough and is a general all-round good R2R op-amp for 5V systems